# RewriteRule only if directory or file does not exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to create a url handler by using php and .htaccess, my problem is that I don't know how to use rewrite condition only if the file\directory entered in the url does not exists.

Comment: Did you even *try* searching?

Comment: Well, I actually did searched for it.

Answer (score 13):

Please have a look at this [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) resource.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
//                                ^ this means file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
//                              ^ this means NOT, "d" means directory.
// Your rewrite rule here.
```

Comment: Note that this only works in a `<Directory>` block or a `.htaccess` file, and not in a `<VirtualHost>` or root config context where the REQUEST_FILENAME has not yet been completed with a full path (since it's not known). In those contexts part of the path must be added to the test manually, since REQUEST_FILENAME will just be the same as REQUEST_URI.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite similar to shell scripting -d and -f functions.

Try something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule XXX
```

Comment: That says: if requested filename *is a file that exists* AND *is a directory that exists*

Answer (score 2):

> '-d' (is directory) Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests
>   whether or not it exists, and is a directory.
>
> '-f' (is regular file) Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests
>   whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.

prefixed by an exclamation mark ('!') to negate their meaning.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it (replace `<filename>`):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* <filename> [L]
```

It does redirection if a file, directory or link does not exist.